# Double click Linux Bash Script and debug with pause commands

Tags: bash, debugging

I'm fairly good with windows .bat scripts and normally use the pause command while developing them so I can see things step by step as the script runs in the command prompt. I am trying to do something similar with a Linux Bash file. I have a very simple bash, which can be seen below...

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World!
read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."
```

I configured Nautilus (a Linux file management program) to "Run executables when they are double clicked" but I don't see anything when I double click the script. Do I need to re-route output to the console or something?

**Edit**

Here is how I achieved what I wanted...

1. Create a .sh file (I am using one from above)
2. Open Nautilus
3. Click Edit -> Preferences -> Behavior tab
4. Under "Executable Text Files" choose "Ask Each Time" Radio button

Now when you click on .sh files, you will be prompted with a few options. Option "Run in Terminal" does exactly what I want. Thanks everyone for the contributions!

Comment: Look at your running processes with `ps -ef`, you *will* see something running there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to launch a terminal, which in turn launches the script.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
xterm -e "echo Hello World; read -p 'Press [Enter] key to exit ..."
```

This is of course impractical for a longer script. But then you can simply do:

```
#!/bin/sh
xterm -e /home/user/scripts/thescript.sh
```

and `thescript.sh` contains all the commands you want to use. Make sure it is executable (`chmod +x thescript.sh`)

Comment: I figured out how to do exactly what I wanted, I added the edit above. What exactly does xterm do?

Comment: Congratulations. Xterm is just a terminal emulator. See `man xterm`. You might prefer another one. E.g. `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 1):

Your script needs a terminal for you to interact with it. One way of doing that is what @Sebastian [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154262/22222). However, note that bash scripts are not really designed to be run this way. A cleaner way would be to write a `.desktop` file that launches your script and then double click *that*. Something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/home/user/yourscript.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

Save that file as `foo.desktop` in your `~/Desktop` folder. That will now appear as an icon there and double clicking it will cause your script to be run in a terminal. Obviously, you need to change `/home/user/yourscript.sh` to the actual path of your script.

Comment: With your terminal emulator, how can we redirect  stdin , stdout and stderr to /dev/null? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank I don't know. I would do it by editing the script itself or writing a wrapper script.

Comment: You can consider [my script here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/674052/318461) to generate these files - just switch `Terminal=` from `false` ([there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/674052/318461)) to `true` ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154410/318461))